# How to print in a given range in one row?

Tags: python

In the first row, I want my program to ask the user number of inputs. For example, let's say 7. When I do:

It doesn't ask for inputs in the same row, but it makes it so it asks for 7 columns. How do I make it so it's only one row?

it should look like :

```
7

1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: can you share the expected output on console ? that isn't clear

Comment: You want first input, and next inputs to be all on one line ?

Comment: so, the n would be 7, and then the second input would be 7 numbers, all in one row. hope that clears it up.

Comment: no that is still unclear, please [edit] your post, and add how it would look in the console

Comment: Asking for `n` is usefull if you want to ask 7 times next, if you want to ask ONCE for multiple values, just do it and split

Comment: I want it to ask once for multiple values, I've edited the post now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out with `map` and give you object and convert into `list`

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    n2=list(map(int,input().split()))
    print(n2)
```

Output:

```
2
input -> (you have to give like this) 1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
input -> (you have to give like this) 2 3 4
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want **one** input to retrieve the values, you don't need another value holding the number (it would be useful only to make **n** inputs)

```
values = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(values)
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I want to have n inputs all in one row. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DinoPoljic Why ? What's the difference ? my answer is exatly what you said "want it to ask once for multiple values"

Answer (score 0):

```
u = int(input("Enter number of inputs: "))
for e in range(1, u+1):
    print(e, end=" ")
```

Here, I would use the "end" keyword so that all numbers in the range are returned on the same line. (: